# How can I sort through multidimensional arrays within multidimensional arrays to eliminate repetitions?

Tags: php

Here is an example output from when I print out its contents:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [CountryA] => Array
            (
                [ProvinceA] => Array
                    (
                        [CityA] => Array
                            (
                                [SuburbA] => 
                            )
                    )
            )
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [CountryA] => Array
            (
                [ProvinceA] => Array
                    (
                        [CityA] => Array
                            (
                                [SuburbB] => 
                            )
                    )
            )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [CountryA] => Array
            (
                [ProvinceB] => Array
                    (
                        [CityB] => Array
                            (
                                [SuburbC] => 
                            )
                    )
            )
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [CountryB] => Array
            (
                [ProvinceD] => Array
                    (
                        [CityE] => Array
                            (
                                [SuburbE] => 
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

What I would like to do is create a function that parses it in some way (and perhaps creates a new array) so that the result will look something like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [CountryA] => Array
            (
                [ProvinceA] => Array
                    (
                        [CityA] => Array
                            (
                                [SuburbA] => 
                                [SuburbB} =>
                            )                       
                    )
                [ProvinceB] =>
                  (
                        [CityB] => Array
                            (
                                [SuburbC] => 
                            )                       
                    )
            )
    )


[1] => Array
    (
        [CountryB] => Array
            (
                [ProvinceD] => Array
                    (
                        [CityE] => Array
                            (
                                [SuburbE] => 
                            )
                    )
            )
    )
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Firstly, [what have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)? Secondly, will the levels always be the same? Will it always be 5 levels deep?

Comment: Thanks for the article. 
I have tried using 'if(in_array($node,$arrayList)' in a few different variations. Right now Im busy trying to get the code to return an acknowledgement that CountryA does in fact exist in the previous iteration of the Array.
Also, some wil be 5 levels deep, some less, and possibly some more.

Comment: Well that will potentially present a problem. For example, what if one entry refers to New York city, and another to New York state? How would you determine to which level the children belong? You really need a rigidly defined structure before you can do this and hope to get sensible results...

Comment: Thats fine though, the code assumes that the hiearchy of values are correct. Also, location is just the example im using.

Answer (score 1):

Change you structure, your array should not look like this :

```
 Array(
   [0] => Array([Country A] => data),
   [1] => Array([Country B] => data)
 )
```

But more like this :

```
 Array(
   [Country A] => data,
   [Country B] => data
 )
```

Once you've done this, it will be trivial to add a city in your array :

- If the country exists in the array, add to the country, else add it to the array and stop
- [Add to country :] If the province exists in the country, add to the province, else add the province to  the array and stop
- Same for city, suburb... you get the idea